# How to Implement $bucket to group by multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

At first [bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) by age and `boundaries` is `[0,20,30,40,50,200]`

```
db.user.aggregate(
    {$project: {_id:0, age:{$subtract:[{$year:new Date()}, {$year:"$birthDay"}]} } },
    {$bucket:{
        groupBy:"$age",
        boundaries:[0,20,30,40,50,200]
    }},
    { $project:{ _id:0,age:"$_id",count:1 } }
)
```

got below result

```
{ "count" : 5, "age" : 20 }
{ "count" : 1, "age" : 30 }
```

then further I want to stat every age range count of each city

```
{ city : "SH", age: 20, count: 2 }
{ city : "BJ", age: 20, count: 3 }
{ city : "BJ", age: 30, count: 1 }
```

So in this case how to implement it ?

In addition

```
db.user.aggregate(
    { $project: {_id:0, city:1, age:{$subtract:[{$year:new Date()}, {$year:"$birthDay"}]} } },
    { $group: { _id:"$city",ages:{$push:"$age"} } },
    { $project: {_id:0, city:"$_id",ages:1} }
)

{ "city" : "SH", "ages" : [ 26, 26 ] }
{ "city" : "BJ", "ages" : [ 27, 26, 26, 36 ] }
```

Comment: What do the source documents look like? Could do with a sample and a clear picture of the result you want to get to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are talking about is actually implemented with [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/), within a regular [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) stage:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "city": "$city",
      "age": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": { 
            "age": { "$subtract" :[{ "$year": new Date() },{ "$year": "$birthDay" }] }
          },
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                { "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", 20 ] }, "then": 0 },
                { "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", 30 ] }, "then": 20 },
                { "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", 40 ] }, "then": 30 },
                { "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", 50 ] }, "then": 40 },
                { "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", 200 ] }, "then": 50 }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

With the results:

```
{ "_id" : { "city" : "BJ", "age" : 30 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "city" : "BJ", "age" : 20 }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "city" : "SH", "age" : 20 }, "count" : 2 }
```

The [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) pipeline stage only takes a single field path. You can have multiple accumulators via the `"output"` option, but the `"groupBy"` is a single expression.

Note you can also use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) here in preference to a separate [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline stage to calculate the "age".

N.B If you actually throw some erroneous expressions to [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) you will get errors about [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/), which should hint to you that this is how it is implemented internally.

---

If you are worried about coding in the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) then just generate it:

```
var ranges = [0,20,30,40,50,200];
var branches = [];
for ( var i=1; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  branches.push({ "case": { "$lt": [ "$$age", ranges[i] ] }, "then": ranges[i-1] });
}

db.user.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "city": "$city",
      "age": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "age": { 
              "$subtract": [{ "$year": new Date() },{ "$year": "$birthDay" }]
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$switch": { "branches": branches }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks! I also implement it by using Map-Reduce,  and I feel in some situations, e.g there are many branches, this map-reduce manner is more preferred. Please see my answer below

Comment: @zhuguowei probably not a great idea. Map reduce runs quite a bit slower compared to native operations. And all you need do is the same kind of `for` loop to generate the conditions in the `$switch` here. In fact I nearly wrote that in, but was basically going to wait for you to ask.

Comment: @zhuguowei In fact, added. Simple example that I don't think you realized how simple it is.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Just compare `for loop` with `switch`, switch only need one compare but `for loop` averagely need  `array.length / 2` times compare. I don't know if c++ could have some `JIT` like java could do some optimization for hot code

Comment: @zhuguowei I think you are going way off topic here and need to do some reading. That is what the links in the answer are for. Read them

Answer (score 0):

Supply another implementation by using [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/)

```
db.user.mapReduce(
    function(){
        var age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.birthDay.getFullYear();
        var ages = [0,20,30,40,50,200]
        for(var i=1; i<ages.length; i++){
            if(age < ages[i]){
                emit({city:this.city,age:ages[i-1]},1);
                break;
            }
        }        
    },
    function(key, counts){
        return Array.sum(counts);
    },
    { out: "user_city_age_count" }
)
```